Count triangles of a shape
Assume you are supposed to count the number of triangles of this shape:

What would be your strategy to count them as fast as possible, accurately?
It just looks mind-boggling to me.
What I have tried:

Upper-right section has 3:

2 single-shape triangles
1 double-share triangles


Upper-left section has 4:

2 single-shape triangles
2 double-shape triangles


Upper section has 2 triangles by combining right & left sections

So, upper section has 9 triangles.
Lovely symmetry gives us another 9 triangles at the bottom.

Triangles by combining up & bottom sections 2+4:

2 triangles on the left
4 triangles on the right



So, in total, we will have 9+9+2+4 triangles i.e. 24. Am I right?
I am looking for a convenient trick to count such things easily.

Have you tried any work yourself? You might try to "divide and conquer" to get most of the triangles.

How many sets of 3 points are there? How many sets do not form a triangle? Is there any symmetry you can use?

I'd count the ones that contain the rightmost vertex (using symmetry) and then erase that vertex and the associated edges and keep counting.

@OscarLanzi Right. I added what I have tried so far.

Typically counting triangles is error prone because one can potentially

count some triangles multiple times

not count some triangles


There are two ways to reduce or even eliminate these errors.
First order all line segments and all corner points. Perhaps naming numerically and/or alphabetically. This is tedious but feasible.

Sequentially, for every line segment, count triangles it participates to.

To do so: sequentially, go over all possible opposite corner points.

Sequentially, for every corner point, count triangles it participates to.

To do so: sequentially, go over all possible opposite line segments.
Because line segments and corner points are ordered there is less or even no chance to not count triangles or to count triangles multiple times.
Of course in both procedures one counts triangles 3 times so one needs to divide by 3.
see for example my answer in PSE:
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/126241/professor-rackbrane-count-the-triangles/126246#126246

1) How many triangles consist of one single shape? => eight
2) How many triangles consist of two single shapes? => seven (I think)
...
10) How many triangles consist of ten single shapes? => zero

Just add everything together :-)
